# JQuery: Are there any downsides of using only one listener for all buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I am currently working on a jquery implementation of tictactoe in order to learn jquery. In my html I defined nine buttons like this:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="column-center"><button id="1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px"></button></div>
        <div class="column-left"><button id="2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px"></button></div>
        <div class="column-right"><button id="3" style="width: 100px; height: 100px"></button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column-center"><button id="4" style="width: 100px; height: 100px"></button></div>
        <div class="column-left"><button id="5" style="width: 100px; height: 100px"></button></div>
        <div class="column-right"><button id="6" style="width: 100px; height: 100px"></button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column-center"><button id="7" style="width: 100px; height: 100px"></button></div>
        <div class="column-left"><button id="8" style="width: 100px; height: 100px"></button></div>
        <div class="column-right"><button id="9" style="width: 100px; height: 100px"></button></div>
    </div>
```

When implementing the jquery logic i thought it would be nice if I would only use one listener for all those buttons, because they are all doing the same thing, I did it like that:

```
    $("button").on('click', function () {
  if(this.id==1||this.id==2||this.id==3||this.id==4||this.id==5||this.id==6||this.id==7||this.id==8||this.id==9){
        $("#"+String(this.id)).css("background-color",$("#color1").css('backgroundColor'));
        $("#"+String(this.id)).prop('disabled', true);
        //all the other logic here...
    }
    else if (this.id==startGame) {
      //start the Game
    }
});
```

I have three questions here:

1. What about performance is it worse than using one listener for every button?
2. Is it good practice do implement the listener like that?
3. Are there any downsides (e.g. some weird bugs that could happen)?

Comment: Look into event delegation and event bubbling. If you have a multitude of things to click, event delegation solves that problem.

Comment: You could do ... `$('.container').find('button').on('click', function(e) {...` or `$(document).on('click', '.container button', function(e)` too :)

Comment: that does the same thing. find will return an array of  jquery elements and bind an event to each one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What about performance is it worse than using one listener for every button?

No.

> Is it good practice do implement the listener like that?

It's fine, though I would separate out the number buttons from the other as they're really unrelated. Delegation might be better for the number buttons, and there are details in your implementation you could probably improve, but the overall concept is fine.

> Are there any downsides (e.g. some weird bugs that could happen)?

No more so than with anything else.

---

For instance, I'd probably look at it like this (assumes a container around the game that doesn't have the "Start game" button in it):

```
// Delegation for the number buttons
$("#container-for-the-game").on("click", "button", function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", $("#color1").css('backgroundColor'))
           .prop('disabled', true);
    //all the other logic here...
});
// Start game separately, as it's unrelated
$("#startGame").on("click", function() {
    //start the Game
});
```

There's an important change above, which is that I switch from

```
$("#"+String(this.id))
```

to

```
$(this)
```

Notes about that:

- `id` values are already strings, no need to use `String(...)` on it.
- You'll get people telling you you can't use `id` values that are all digits. You can, it's perfectly fine, but note the next bullet point.
- Technically, `#1` and such are *invalid CSS selectors*. jQuery tolerates them provided they're on their own like that (as a by-product of optimizing to a `getElementById` call instead of `querySelectorAll`), but a CSS ID selector cannot start with an unescaped digit. While `$("#1")` works (with the current jQuery), `$("#1 span")` wouldn't (to find a `span` as a descendant of the element with the `id` "1"). Best to avoid the habit.
- `this` is already the button that was clicked, so there's no need for a DOM lookup.
- Unless you're using those `id` values for something else (I suspect you probably are), you don't need them.

Comment: I used the id values to, for example enable all buttons by using a for loop, when a new game is started. But this would work the same if I would call them button1, button2, ..., button9, too. So `#button1` would be a valid css selector?

Comment: @frankenapps: Yes. The issue with `#1` as a selector is that it starts with a digit. `#button1` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

the right way to attach a single listener in your code would be something like

```
$('.container').on('click', 'button', listenerFn)
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

here you truly create a single listener to handle all the current and future buttons you might add. there are no downsides in performance other than the fact that JQ has to check the original target for matching selector. This is actually the recommended approach for multiple reasons.

1. too many listeners can produce memory problems.
2. code is more maintainable and readable
3. you can remove and add buttons w/o having to detach or attach new event listeners

if you have to be more specific about what buttons to bind to, add a class to those and then in the on selector use `button.class`.

Hope this helps

Comment: *"too many listeners can produce memory problems."* The OP's original had **one** function attached to multiple elements. The overhead on that is purely attaching it (the function is not duplicated). There is no significant memory improvement using delegation.

Comment: taking into account modern browsers etc you don't have "significant" improvements but you do get some and the function it self is not the problem is the number of listeners not the number of handlers what can cause you to have performance issues if you are running a low memory setting. As general rules avoiding unnecessary listeners is good idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is no downside of attaching listener like that. Rather I found it convenient. It makes the code more manageable and you will be able to identify and solve the bugs more easily in future.

You can also add data-dash attribute or class in your button rather than using generic button tag to attach event. I think that part of your code may create bug in future.